# Convert maps from different coordinates scale in Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: convert

I need help to convert position of objects on map to a new scale.

1. Coordinate (0, 0) is the top left corner of the map.
2. Currently, 1 point distance is X
3. I need to convert 1 point distance to be Y
4. I need to update the location of each object on the map to the new scale

What I was thinking to do is this:

1. The scale is `X:Y`, which is basically `x/y`. Let `K = X/Y`
2. Fore each object on the map with coordinates obj_x and obj_y, new coordinates are calculated the following way:

   new_obj_x := obj_x / K

   new_obj_y := obj_y / K

Is this correct? I have a feeling that something is very worng

Comment: Are you using a geographic or projected coordinate system?  Are you using any GIS software?

Comment: I have a simple rectangular map. I am not using any software, I am writing a small program.

Comment: It sounds like you have a [Cartesian coordinate system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)

Comment: Yes. Just one little thing to note, point (0, 0) is on top left corner and X coord increases when moving to right and Y increases when going down

Comment: For help with coding questions we need you to present a code snippet that illustrates what you are trying to do with both your expected and observed results.  Telling us precisely what you did will be much more useful than just telling us basically what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Applying an **affine transformation** to each data point should do it. You may find it helpful to review the following information:

http://www.quantdec.com/GIS/affine.htm#Scaling

http://www.perrygeo.com/python-affine-transforms.html

Comment: This is what I basically did. However, I am not sure I calculated correctly the scaling factor